# Batch file when run as admin cannot read file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

when I run a batch file with the code below, I get the error `The system cannot find the file specified.`. log.log actually exists, before anyone snipes on me for that. Anyone know what's wrong?

```
 :READ
cls
echo Reading definitions...
(
  Set /p s1=
  Set /p s2=
  Set /p s3=
  Set /p s4=
  Set /p s5=
  Set /p s6=
  Set /p s7=
  Set /p s8=
  Set /p s9=
  Set /p s10=
)<log.log
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are expecting to happen. Are you thinking that the first ten (10) lines of the log.log file will be put into the environment variables? What does log.log look like?

Comment: When you run a batch file as admin the working directory is set to the SYSTEM32 directory.  Your log.log file does not exist in that directory.

Comment: @lit, yes his code will work if it can find the file.

Comment: Change your redirection to `)<"%~dp0log.log"`.  This will give it the full path to where the batch file is, which I assume your log file is as well.

Comment: @Squashman and LotPings : Thanks! Sorry I haven't been online, I've been busy with other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be less redundant and incorporating @Squashman's hint:

```
:READ
cls
echo Reading definitions...
(For /l %%s in (1,1,10) Do Set /p s%%s=)<"%~dp0log.log"
```